# echo "&" rather than "&amp;"

Tags: php, javascript

I am using following url

```
$url="index.php?option=my_com&task=ABC&view=new"
```

now i'm just adding this url in java script

```
alert("<?php echo $url?>");
```

The output is

```
index.php?option=my_com&amp;task=ABC&amp;view=new
```

`"&"` is replace by `"&amp;"`

I want to display actual url. :(

Comment: Your vague description of what your code looks like does not include any step where `&` may be encoded as `&amp;`. You are not going to get helpful answers unless you post some real code.

Comment: `alert(<?php echo $url?>);` should throw a syntax error (in JavaScript).

Comment: @Felis:: its common-scene. alert("<?php echo $url?>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert( '<?php echo $url?>'.replace(/\&amp\;/gi, "&");
```

Comment: This is more like dealing with the consequences and not solving the problem at its root.

Answer (score 0):

You must enclose the URL in quotes:

```
alert("<?php echo($url); ?>");
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wGALJ/).

Comment: I don't think that's needed in php -- `echo $url` should work just fine too.

Comment: @Liv: That's not PHP, it's JavaScript, which requires strings to be quoted.

Comment: i want to add url from PHP to jquery. your above code is not work according my requirment. :(

Answer (score 0):

encode url. [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)